# Flutter firebase: get data from collectionGroup

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How do I access data in a collectionGroup?

`StreamBuilder( stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup("collection-group-name").snapshot; builder: (context, snapshot){ if (snapshot.hasData){} return Text() //What should I put in this text field if I want to return a specific data? } )`

Comment: add a screenshot of this collection from firebase.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.